# asp.net form to html file, saving control content

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to save an asp.net form with multiples textbox and checkbox to an html file.

Problem is, even though I have postback/viewstate enabled for these controls, the content of the textbox and state of the checkbox is not saved when I do this(when the user press the submit button).

```
        WebClient myClient = new WebClient();
        string myPageHTML = null;
        byte[] requestHTML;
        // Gets the url of the page
        string currentPageUrl = Request.Url.ToString();

        UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();

        requestHTML = myClient.DownloadData(currentPageUrl);

        myPageHTML = utf8.GetString(requestHTML);
        ///////////////
        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test.html");
        file.WriteLine(myPageHTML);

        file.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're creating a brand new HttpRequest to "currentPageUrl".  This is essentially the same thing as opening a new browser and requesting that URL: it is a brand new request, with no viewstate.  That is why it returns you a brand new response, with no values filled in.

Sure, you're firing the request from within the page's own code behind.  However, the webserver doesn't know that - it will do exactly what you requested: serve up a brand new version of the requested page.

**EDIT - more info:**
One thing that might work (though admittedly I haven't tried it) would be to grab the HttpResponse after Render() has executed, and read the page's full content from Response.Output stream.

Comment: Hoo you're right I'm saving a brand new page, I will try what you said below thx :)